# Find the least(smallest) natural number for (n)

Tags: combinatorics

If for sets $A_1$,$A_2$ and $A_3$, we have :

$$A_1=\{2,3,4,..,200\}$$ $$A_2=\{5,6,7,...,199\}$$$$A_3=\{8,9,10,...,198\}$$then what's the smallest natural number $n$ , for which $(A_1∩A_2∩A_3∩...∩A_n) =∅$

Comment: This is a math olympiad question, please help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any $A_n=\{3n−1,3n,..,201−n\}$.

$A_{n+1}$ will be a subset of $A_n$ for all n $\implies (A_1∩A_2∩A_3∩...∩A_i)=A_i$

Also, $A_n$ will be a null set when $3n-1>201-n\implies n>202/4\implies n=51$

Comment: But yet would you please explain why should 3n-1 be larger than 201-n so that An is going to be a null set?

Comment: @Prophet you're welcome. As I said, the set is $A_n=\{3n−1,3n,..,201−n\}$. If $3n-1<201-n$, my set will still have those elements. Even if $3n−1=201−n$,my set will have one element (it isn't possible in this case btw otherwise n won't be an integer). I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Since each set is a subset of the preceding one, the intersection is just the last set.  How many elements are in set $A_i$?  When is it zero?

Comment: Nothing else is mentioned in the problem

Comment: You are clearly expected to extrapolate the sets $A_4, A_5 \ldots$ from the pattern.  The problem is very badly stated not to say that.